# How to set exact date tick in matplotlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

-- Python 3.5 --

I am working on a project where I can have little data to map into a graph 
Which can vary from 7 to 200 point on graph.
X axis contains date and when number of records on graph increase the dates get clustered which makes graph kinda unreadable.

Is there anyway I can limit the tick to 4 on x axis (time is plotted) always no matter how many records.

I tried using `locator_params()` but it does not work with time.

Any suggestion or workaround will always be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When plotting dates with matplotlib, you want to use the locators and formatters from [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html).

Here, you may use the [`AutoDateLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator)

```
matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator(tz=None, minticks=4, maxticks=4)
```

where

> `maxticks` is the maximum number of ticks desired, which controls any interval between ticks (ticking every other, every 3, etc.).

An example on how to use these locators and formatters is given [on the matplotlib page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html).

Comment: Can you guide me on how to use AutoDateLocator with pylab
An example will be appreciated.

Comment: And I want 4 ticks only for the X axis.

Comment: The link in my answer was meant as a guide. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390874/4124317) uses an `AutoDateLocator`.